# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I have the below code in which i am getting the strange error.

```
   function export_to_excel()

     {

    results_html = $('report_excel').innerHTML;
    results_html = '<html><body><table  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="9"><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td colspan="9"></td></tr>' + results_html + '</table></body></html>';
    var input = new Element('input', {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'results[html]',
        'value': results_html
    });
    var form = new Element('form', {
        'method': 'post',
        'name': 'Employee Salary Register',
        'action': "html_to_excel"
    });
    form.insert(input);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

The error is occurring at this line

```
results_html = '<html><body><table  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="9"><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td colspan="9"></td></tr>' + results_html + '</table></body></html>';
```

**EDIT:**

The error is showing in the console of  *Firebug* pointing to that line.I just attached a Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

There you can see,under the Two Buttons(print and Export),the code is appearing on the screen.Those code lines are part of the function `export_to_excel()`

It does works perfectly in my Local Server too. I'm Using *PrototypeJS* and I'm sorry for the Misleading and sorry for the delay too.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Works in the console of Chrome if you change `results_html` to a random string without quotes, how does `results_html` look like?

Comment: What is report_excel exactly?

Comment: @MrLister: It is the id of the table which i have and am using it in the above code to export that data into an xls format.

Comment: To be clear, the above code is working fine in local server but at client side it is not working and that strange error is appearing in the console.Files are exactly same though...

Comment: Looks like it depends on 'report_excel' content.
Btw if you're using jQuery you should change `.innerHTML` to `.html()`, and if report_excel is the id of some element than add # in front of it `$('#report_excel')`.

Comment: A few suggestions: (1)Try changing the file extension of the exported file to assure that the client doesn't have a problem specifically with .xls format.  (2) change your first results_html to results_html1; then update the next line to be:  results_html = '<html><body><table  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="9"><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td colspan="9"></td></tr>' + results_html1 + '</table></body></html>';

Comment: You should include the console error you are getting in your question. It would help us to help you.

Comment: what does this return? $('report_excel').innerHTML;

Comment: `$(id)` and `new Element` both suggest the use of _prototypejs_, so I took the liberty of adding that tag. In prototypejs, `$` is an alias for `document.getElementById`. See also: http://api.prototypejs.org/

Comment: @Pavan: In 4 months, you haven't got any further than the observation that you got a syntax error in a line of code that appears to be syntactically correct. The least you could have done is write a unit test around that particular line of code to **prove** that the error occurs in that particular line of code. I am eagerly awaiting your jsfiddle.

Comment: @Ruud I Just Edited my Question!

Comment: @Pavan: Still blurry, so I have more questions, sorry. Have you tried other web browsers (IE/Chrome/Safari)? I suppose button _Export_ calls `export_to_excel`. Those weird lines underneath the buttons, are they there already when the page loads, or do they appear once you click the button? I hope I understood correctly: error occurs on production environment only, not on your local environment. Is there a difference in the version of prototypejs? Please add `console.log(results_html);` just above the line giving the error, and show us the result (see console); both when error, and when ok?

Comment: It works fine in chrome.Yes the function export_to_excel refers to Export button.Those lines are already exists when the page loads.And now unfortunately,the server at the client side is changed and now the error doesn't appear. Now I just need to know why that error appeared before.

Comment: @Pavan: If nobody (including yourself) can reproduce the problem, then there's never going to be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented your code below, and it works well
First Define your id/class first in this line `results_html = $('report_excel').innerHTML;`

```
function export_to_excel(){

    results_html = $('report_excel').innerHTML;
    results_html = "<html><body><table  align='center' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'><tr><td colspan='9'><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td colspan='9'></td></tr>" + results_html + "</table></body></html>";
    var input = new Element('input', {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'results[html]',
        'value': results_html
    });
    var form = new Element('form', {
        'method': 'post',
        'name': 'Employee Salary Register',
        'action': "html_to_excel"
    });
    form.insert(input);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion: Change your line from:

```
results_html = '<html><body><table  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="9"><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td colspan="9"></td></tr>' + results_html + '</table></body></html>'
```

to

```
results_html = "<html><body><table  align='center' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'><tr><td colspan='9'><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td colspan='9'></td></tr>" + results_html + "</table></body></html>";
```

I have replaced **"** with **'** and viceversa.. This would probably remove your error.Hopefully.

NOTE: Since in comment you mentioned that **$('report_excel')** is actually you tableId the correct jquery way to access id is **$("#report_excel")**.. **Use #**

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but its JavaScript not JQuery

Comment: @Pavan the reason he is referring to jQuery is that the $('') syntax is something used in jQuery, as well as Mootools.  Both are JavaScript Libraries (so just reusable JavaScript functions). So it appears you are using some sort of library in order to do the $('') syntax. Otherwise what do you think the $('') should be doing, if you want raw javascript you would want `document.getElementById('report_excel').innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the quotes inside your results_html content.

It seems you are using jQuery, (1) If you are :

```
results_html = $('report_excel').innerHTML;
results_html_container = $('<html><body><table  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="9"><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td colspan="9"></td></tr>' + results_html + '</table></body></html>';
results_html_container.html(results_html);
```

2.If you are not : Escape the single quotes in your content.

```
   results_html = $('report_excel').innerHTML;   
   results_html = '<html><body><table  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td
   colspan="9"><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td
    colspan="9"></td></tr>' + results_html.replace(/'/g, "\\'"); +
    '</table></body></html>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function export_to_excel() {
    var results_html = $('report_excel').html() ? $('report_excel').html() : "";
    results_html = '<html><body><table  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="9"><b>Employee Salary Register </b></td></tr><tr><td colspan="9"></td></tr>' + results_html + '</table></body></html>';
    var input = new Element('input', {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'results[html]',
        'value': results_html
    });
    var form = new Element('form', {
        'method': 'post',
        'name': 'Employee Salary Register',
        'action': "html_to_excel"
    });
    form.append(input);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
</script>
```

The code is a bit more readable as well as using proper jQuery instead of a mix-match which causes problems (as in your case).

I declared the variable, checked if the element had a value otherwise defaulted to a blank string. Added the input to the form by means of appending.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but I had a similar problem and I'll leave my fix here for anyone else who gets to this by googling the error. I was trying to include a local fallback to cdn hosted angular:

```
<script> //THIS IS WRONG.
window.angular || document.write('<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>');
</script>
```

That was throwing the same unterminated string literal error. It turned out that the end script tag in the document write string was tripping up the parser. Just escape the slash in the quoted closing tag.

```
<script> //correct version.
window.angular || document.write('<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Hat tip: [HTML5 Boilerplate Project.](https://html5boilerplate.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the javascript code into a separate file (like exportExcel.js) and then include that file from your view. NOT use the  tag!